# How to select a checkbox in protractor? (Issue in a specific case)

Tags: protractor

I am facing rather a weird issue with checking/unchecking  checkbox. I am trying by creating an entity and then editing the same (form) and i have to enter some text fields first and then check/uncheck checkbox based on the input from .yaml file. Everything works fine in Create flow but in edit flow it is not clicking the checkbox sometimes when we edit some text field first. It works fine when the checkbox action is done first and then the text field is edited.

I have added logs in the code and verified that isSelected and input from .yaml is validated and the code reaches the correct loop but still it doesn't click it

```
selectCheckBox = (label: string, select: boolean) => {   
    const checkBox = element(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"' + label + '")]//preceding::input[@type="checkbox"][1]'));
    const checkBoxLabel = element(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"' + label + '")]//preceding::input[@type="checkbox"][1]//following::label[1]'));
    checkBox.isSelected().then(function(value) {
      console.log('isSelect value : ' + value + ' & toSelect value : ' + select);
      if (select && !value) {
        console.log('not selected and have to select ' + label);
        checkBoxLabel.click();
      } else if (value && !select) {
        console.log('selected and have to deselect ' + label);
        checkBoxLabel.click();
      } else {
        console.log('checkbox is already selected/deselected');
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Just an update. Clicking on TAB via protractor before clicking the checkbox seems to work. But can someone explain why this and if there is any better solution

Comment: can you please share the html source that you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this method in your framework

```
/**
*  toggleCheckbox
*  @param    {ElementFinder}      $element          Locator of INPUT element
*  @param    {boolean}            [state=true]      Enable/disable
*  @return   {promise.Promise}
*/
toggleCheckbox: ($element, state = true) => {
  return $element.isSelected().then(
    actualState => actualState !== state && browser.executeScript(
      "arguments[0].click();",
      $element.getWebElement()
    )
  )
}
```

And then use like this in a spec

```
await toggleCheckbox($yourElement, true);
// OR
await toggleCheckbox($yourElement, false);
```

If that'll help you I'll explain why your code doesn't work